# Play! Framework and Uniformjs don't play nicely for file uploading

Tags: javascript, playframework, uniform

I am writing a small webapp in Play!, and trying to use UniformJS (http://uniformjs.com/) to make my form elements look good.  One page of the app lets users upload a file:

```
#{ form @Application.upload(), id:'uploadform', enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile"/>
<input type="submit" id="surveyChooseFileButton" class="button" value="Upload" />
#{/form}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
public static void upload(@Required File uploadFile, @Required String surveyName) {
...
}
```

This is all just like one of the Play! examples (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/5things#a5.Straightforwardfileuploadmanagementa), and that all works fine.  The problem is when I apply Uniform to my file input:

```
$(function(){ $("input:file").uniform(); });
```

Now the controller receives a null File object!  Is there any way around this?

**UPDATE:**

Removing the id's doesn't do it (although that seemed very plausible!).  View-source on the offending element reveals:

```
<div id="uniform-uploadFile" class="uploader">  <!-- A new div -->
   <!-- My input element turns invisible --> 
   <input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="uploadFile" size="19" style="opacity: 0;">  

   <!-- Uniform adds these -->
   <span class="filename" style="-moz-user-select: none;">No file selected</span> 
   <span class="action" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Select</span>
</div>
```

Still no idea what's going on, but this is the end result.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it works if you disable uniform?

Comment: As little sense as it makes, yes.  Taking "input:file" out of the Uniform initialization makes it work immediately.

Comment: Try to remove the ids, after a quick look at Uniform source code, it enhances with classes and id.

Comment: @Zenklys Removing the ids didn't help, but it was educational.  See my edit above.

Comment: What browser are you using? Has this been tested with other browser?

Comment: I've been testing in Chrome.  As it turns out, it also fails in Firefox and works in IE8, which is news to me.

Answer (score 0):

I build your page using play-1.2.3 and uniform-2446d99, and in ff 3.6.20 it seems to work fine here. What version of play! are you using?